# How to trigger a ONE TIME SHOW Form in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, changelog

**What i am asking for is if there's a way to show a Form 1 time (the first time after a new version is installed) bacuse i've tried it with the event Form.Shown and it is showing the form everytime the Application is opened.**

I want this to create a changelog form  that it's only showed when a new version is installed
I've also tried using Settings but i was not succesful

Comment: _also tried using Settings but i was not succesful...._ How? Do you keep an entry for the current version? See also [ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) method.

Comment: Add an xml file to compare with the server's xml file. If there is no match, update information is displayed. You can search for a lot of content.

Comment: thank you so much, i've implemented a code that dows that.

Comment: Hi Radio Barcelona, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)